# What are the historical reasons for the conventional map orientation?

Tags: maps, cartography

North is traditionally shown upwards in maps, although there isn't any physical reason for it - compass needles point parallel to magnetic field lines. Showing south as up would be just as legitimate.

Are there any historical reasons for the conventional map orientation?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The convention was established by [Ptolemy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptolemy) (AD 90 – c. AD 168) in his main work, [Geography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographia_%28Ptolemy%29). The following is a 15<sup>th</sup> century reconstruction of [Ptolemy's world map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptolemy_world_map):

[image: Ptolemy's world map]

It's an arbitrary decision, and several [reversed maps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reversed_map) exist. There are also maps that don't follow a [standard orientation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map#Orientation_of_maps), some examples are [T and O maps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T_and_O_map), [polar maps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_map), and [Dymaxion/Fuller maps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dymaxion_map). Interestingly the iconic 1972 [Blue Marble photograph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Blue_Marble), taken by the [Apollo 17](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_17) crew, was reversed to fit the traditional view.

Further reading:

- [On maps, why is north always up?](http://www.straightdope.com/columns/read/441/on-maps-why-is-north-always-up)
- [The Upsidedown Map Page](http://www.flourish.org/upsidedownmap/)
- [Cartography article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartography) on Wikipedia

Comment: You beat me to the answer. +1

Comment: Wow, I never knew that Ptolemy was that accurate.

Comment: Thank you. Why was this closed as off-topic? It's a legitimate question.

Comment: @Alyosha I edited it to be a bit more history focused, and voted to re-open, and so did two others. That, of course, doesn't necessarily mean that the question is on topic, just that me and two others think it is. If the question isn't re-opened in a couple of days, you should post a question on the [Meta site](http://meta.history.stackexchange.com/), asking how to improve it (please read the [Meta FAQ](http://meta.history.stackexchange.com/faq) to see what Meta is about).

Comment: Note that this map was a globe projection. Nice visual proof that both Ptolemy and 15th century Europeans realized that the earth is a globe.